# What's the asp.net equivalent for C/C++ #define?

Tags: asp.net

Can you guys let me know the asp.net equivalent for C/C++ #define? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# has [#define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x%28VS.71%29.aspx) for conditional compilation, but it can only be defined (or not); there is no other value.  For constants, you just use [const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28VS.71%29.aspx) or [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7%28VS.71%29.aspx) as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to place such const variables into a separate file and access them as we do in C ?

Comment: @rocksolid, any field can be `const`, and you can access public (const) fields between classes.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `const` - see similar question: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/224517-c-equivalent-cs-define